# Run python script on AWS EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jar, emr

I am trying to run a python and java application on EMR cluster. I ran my java jar application using the below code and it worked fine.
HadoopJarStepConfig runExampleConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                        .withJar(jar_name)
                        .withArgs(main_arguments);

How can I run my python script instead of the java application?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reading about [script-runner jar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html) on EMR? You can use something like below to submit a python script as EMR step -

```
HadoopJarStepConfig runExampleConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig() 
.withJar(s3://<region>.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar)
.withArgs(s3://bucketname/path-to/script.sh);
```

where  needs to be replaced with appropriate value (eg : us-east-1) based on which region you are launching the EMR cluster.